# Help New User-I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and can't get it to load without USB

Tags: boot

I did it on a surface pro 3 which has windows 8.  I only have two boots.  Boot 00001 is USB. Boot 0000 is Windows. I believe this means I messed up.  Can someone simply walk me through how to fix it.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Can you acces to BIOS config? Dont know if you have keyboard before OS start...if you cant i dont think you can install Ubuntu on it, by USB. If you can acces to BIOS, check that you can change UEFI config for not Win OS only and allow to boot from USB. 
If nothing works, you should google a recovery way for your tablet.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you Nicolas.  I have ubuntu installed which I did by USB.  When I turn on the computer it pretty quickly goes to screen that gives me a few options.  One option is to install ubuntu.  The other is to try to run Ubuntu without installing, which if I do, loads ubuntu. When I search in ubuntu for how many boots I have I only got the two I mentioned above.  However, if I don't have a USB in the computer I get this screen that says things like Trusted Platform Module Enabled Secure Boot Control, etc.  When I exited that screen it keeps looping me back to it but never to an OS. Thank u!

Comment: Let me know if what I said needs clarification. Thanks!

Comment: most of every computers or laptops need to change the UEFI config at the BIOS...try to watch what you have to press to acces BIOS config...it may take some several restarts to get the key you have to press...once on BIOS config search for BOOT...you should see an option for UEFI BOOT and/or CMOS BOOT...select both and try again. If you get to the BIOS config menu, look for some other options that may have stop you launching Ubuntu....like secure boot is enabled...etc. I'll keep watching if you solve this.

Comment: sorry cant help much more

Comment: Hi Nicolas.  The only thing I could do was disable the secure boot.   It really didn't change anything.  The surface has really limited options so that was about all I could do.  I saw some post that I may have need to install GRUB.  Does that mean anything to you?  Thanks, Jim

Comment: But i see you can enter to BIOS config, this should be useful in some way. Try to navigate all the options, they are all pretty obvious and if you dont save changes, nothing bad can happen. To me GRUB is the program that install Ubuntu and make it possible to install it besides other OS. Its on the installer, so i dont think you need to install. Its auto installed. Can you find something about boot devices priority. If you have Ubuntu installed once and at the restart you have the installation windows again you have a problem with the boot priority.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, the only thing I found is is Configure Alternate System Boot Order.  here is a link that shows the options I have on surface 3.  https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/how-to-use-the-bios-uefi?os=windows-8.1-update-1&=undefined#menuW81

Comment: The options for configure alternate system boot order include-SSD Only, Network-USB-SSD-SSD, USB-Network-SSD, USB-SSD, Network-SSD

Comment: Well..then you shoul try any of this config wich put USB before SSD...even if you have network before USB. Just make sure Network its not available so its jumps to USB BOOT...